# Blade Form not showing flash message and is not performing validation on form fields

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

O. I am in need of help with this problem. I have a contact form within a blade.php file, I have a route set up in my web.php file and I have a controller set up which is routed from the web.php file and is to perform validation on the fields and display a flash message on the page when the form is submitted. Right now the form is properly being submitted to my database so it is working but if I submit with a blank form, the validation is not working as it should (laravel) and also the flash message does not show upon successful form submission:

CODE:

Web.php

```
<?php 
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::post('/contact/submit','MessagesController@submit');
```

MessagesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Message;


class MessagesController extends Controller
{

    public function submit(Request $request)
    {

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:2',
            'email' => 'required|max:255',
            'phonenumber' => 'required|min:10|max:10',
            'message' => 'required|min:5',
        ]);

        Message::create($validatedData);

        return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Message has been sent');
    }
}
```

contact.blade.php

```
{{--CONTACT FORM--}}
<section id="contact">
<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row text-center padding">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h2>Contact PDMA</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 padding">
            {!! Form::open(['url' => 'contact/submit']) !!}
            @csrf

            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label("name", 'Name')}}
                {{Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter name'])}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label("email", 'E-Mail Address')}}
                {{Form::text('email', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter email'])}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label("phonenumber", 'Phone Number')}}
                {{Form::text('phonenumber', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter phone number'])}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label("message", 'Message')}}
                {{Form::textarea('message', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter message'])}}
            </div>

            <div>
                {{Form::submit('Submit Form', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}
            </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Session:
First Import Session class in your controller

```
 use Session;

 Message::create($validatedData);
 Session::flash('success', 'Message has been sent');
 return redirect('/')
```

Then Create a blade file in view folder, you can call it whatever you want, e.g: notify.blade.php

```
@if (Session::has('success'))
 <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="bottom:10px; position: fixed; left:2%; z-index:100">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  <h4 class="alert-heading">Well done!</h4>
  <p>{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
 </div>
@endif

@if (Session::has('danger'))
 <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="bottom:10px; position: fixed; left:2%; z-index:100">
   <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
   <h4 class="alert-heading">Error!</h4>
   <p>{{ Session::get('danger') }}</p>
 </div>
@endif
```

Finaly, include this file in any view.

```
include('notify')
```

Answer (score 1):

As liverson suggested create the blade file for the session 
And the other thing you can also is catch the error and  change the input style using another blade something like error.blade.php and include it in your form

```
@if($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

For the Form you can add `{{$errors->has('name') ? 'is-danger' : ''}}` to your div class

For Example

```
<div class="form-row text-left">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-3">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="input {{$errors->has('name') ? 'is-danger' : ''}}" required
                value= @if(isset($user))"{{$user->name}}"@else "{{old('name')}}"@endif>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/15

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. @UBGN